# How to prevent push notification when app is open in angular using PwPush

Tags: angular, angular-pwa

I am using PwPush to push notification from server to desktop. Now if my angular app is already open in chrome I don't want to see push notification instead I just want to update UI. Right now I only get push notification even if app is open or closed. Is there a way to achieve this in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I was going about this wrong way. The push notification shows if I send payload with notification key values pair. but if I send simple payload without notification key then everything works fine like I want. I still get the message and notification is not shown

For visulisation I changed the payload from this

```
      let payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Title',
            body: 'This is my body',
            
            icon: 'assets/icons/icon-384x384.png',
            actions: [
                { action: 'bar', title: 'Focus last' },
                { action: 'baz', title: 'Navigate last' },
            ],
            data: {
                onActionClick: {
                    default: { operation: 'openWindow' },
                    bar: {
                        operation: 'focusLastFocusedOrOpen',
                        url: 'https://www.google.com',
                    },
                    baz: {
                        operation: 'navigateLastFocusedOrOpen',
                        url: '/signin',
                    },
                },
                url:"https://www.google.com",
            },
        },
    };
```

to this

```
      let payload = {
        "body":"some stuff",
    };
```